# Animate a view with base fixed

Tags: android, android-animation

How do i animate a `View` such that its base remains fixed but the rest of the body moves(Image attached)?. For example, in the image, initially the `View` is like (1) and then it animates as (2)->(3).
I tried with `RotateAnimation` but certainly it won't work. Is there a something like `pivot` that i can use with `TranslateAnimation`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom View class and then override its  `onDraw()` method to implement the skew.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
   super.onDraw(canvas); 

   canvas.skew(0.5f, 0.5f);
   ...
}
```